# How to activate the dynamically created tab in tabpanel?

Tags: extjs, tabpanel

How to activate the dynamically created tab in tabpanel?
I am inserting new tab using below code and its adding successfully.

tabpanel.insert(tabIndex, tabConfig);

**tabConfig**:-

[image]

Comment: Ext js version 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Call setActiveTab method `tabpanel.setActiveTab(tabConfig)`

Answer (score 1):

```
tabpanel.insert(2, {
        title: 'Baz',
        tabConfig: {
        title: 'Buzzzzzz',
        tooltip: 'Buz ToolTip'
    }   
    });

    tabpanel.setActiveTab(2);
}
```

Comment: I tried but it does not showing dynamically added tab. e.g: i have tow tabs and third on dynamically added then tabpanel only shows items of two tabs not dynamically addd one. so in this case setActiveTab wont work

Answer (score 1):

tabPanel.setActiveTab(tabIndex) is what you need. Note that tabIndex will be zero indexed i.e for selecting Tab 2 you have to pass tabIndex as 1. Here is a fiddle I created for your reference : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1b9i